# Prove that every elementary matrix is invertible, and the inverse is again an elementary matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that there are many proofs regarding this. However, the book i'm using seems to suggest another way to do it without giving an answer. What i mean by the another way is some other proofs that do not use the fact that elementary row operation can be expressed by multiplying elementary matrices. The book says **that the lemma need to be proved only when the size of identity matrix is 2 by 2**. Does it have something to do with mathematical induction? That is, did the author want us to find out both induction hypothesis and induction step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will take $K$ a field, $n\geq 1$ and identify matrices $M_n(K)$ with linear endomorphisms of the space $K^n$ using the canonical base $(e_1,...,e_n)$ of this space.

I think I see what this means. Let us set :

$$(E_{k,l})_{i,j}=1 \text{ if } i=k\text{ and } j=l $$

$$(E_{k,l})_{i,j}=0 \text{ otherwise} $$

Then the elementary matrices are $I_n+\lambda E_{k,l}$ with $k\neq l$, $\lambda\in K$ and $\phi$ the corresponding linear application. Now to show that such a matrix is invertible we will decompose the space :

$$K^n=Vect(e_k,e_l)\oplus Vect(e_1,...,\hat{e_k},...,\hat{e_l},...,e_n) $$

Clearly $\phi$ respect this sum and induce identity on the second space. On the first space it induces :

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&\lambda\\0&1\end{pmatrix} $$

Which is an elementary matrix which is $2$ by $2$.If I can invert this one then I can invert $\phi$ by taking the direct sum of the inverse of the $2$ by $2$ matrix on $Vect(e_k,e_l)$ and identity on the other subspace.

There is no induction in this proof.

Comment: I think it should be $I_n+\lambda E_{kl}$, for more generality (row operations usually involve a coefficient). But the proof won't change much

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, I was not sure about the definition of elementary matrix, I edited, thanks.